# Extract date from pubDate RSS tag

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

Developing Android app and need to parse pubDate tag from RSS. There is no problem to display actual time from this tag but it's too long

`<pubDate>Wed, 15 Nov 2017 14:46:40 +0000</pubDate>`

What I'm really interested here is how can date, in this case `15 Nov`
be extracted. Furthermore, I would like to compare dates and display posts in descending order based on pubDate tag .

Answer (score 0):

If you use Rome to read RSS, you can format pubDate like as below.
https://rometools.github.io/rome/

getPubDate() returns Date type. You can sort or  compare by stream operations.

```
import com.rometools.rome.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
import com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput;
import com.rometools.rome.io.XmlReader;

import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class NewsService {

    public List<String> getNews(String url) throws Exception {
        // read RSS
        SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedInput().build(new XmlReader(new URL(url)));
        // format pubDate and create pubDate string list
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM");
        return feed.getEntries().stream().map(i -> i.getPublishedDate()).map(sdf::format).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java Class Library can parse RSS date/time values.

RSS date/time values are in [RFC 822 format](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#data-types-datetime). You can parse one of these dates using the `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes in the `java.text` package.

First, create a date formatter for RFC 822 and use it to parse the string in the `pubdate` element:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
Date pubdate = formatter.parse("Wed, 15 Nov 2017 14:46:40 +0000");
```

The call to `parse()` throws a `ParseException` from the `java.text` package, so you must surround it with a `try`/`catch` or use a `throws` clause in the method.

Next, create a calendar and set it to that date:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(pubdate);
```

Finally, get the month and day of month from that calendar.

```
    System.out.println("Month: " + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    System.out.println("Day: " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```